# what does error mean and how to fix it

Tags: xml, xml-simple

```
<currentversion vob="<vobname>" label="<labal>"/>

<export vob="<vobname>" branch="<branch>" label="<label>"/>
```

error :

> The value of attribute "v" associated
>   with an element type "currentversion"
>   must not contain the '<' character.

Comment: You can't use `<` or `>` in a value-string. The fact that they're inside quotes is not enough.

Comment: no i tried already but still same error

Comment: if you still have the error, than who is producing that error? Not the XML parser. Maybe the program that is supposed to work with the VALUEs expected something different.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<` with `&lt;` (lt=lower than) and `>` with `&gt;` (gt = greater than) if it is not part of a tag...

```
<currentversion vob="&lt;vobname&gt;" label="&lt;labal&gt;"/>
```

Comment: Since the < and > characters are used in XML to specifically indicate the beginning and end of tags, they are not allowed in the quoted attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means exactly what it says, and you fix it by ensuring that all `"&"` and `"<"` characters in your data are escaped as `"&amp;"` and `"&lt;"` respectively.